# Capturing a file POSTed to PHP without writing to disk

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io

Is there a way to have PHP capture a file being uploaded (POSTed) such that PHP can manipulate the file before it is ever written to disk?

Example application: A form where a user can upload a file to my web application, and my application encrypts it with PGP before it ever is written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are stored as temporary files by PHP until you manipulate them (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). You can use INI settings to control where the files are stored, but you can't really intercept them before they are written to a temp location.

You can certainly PGP encrypt them before you move the file into its final location.

Comment: Right.  Is there any way to use PHP to handle the raw upload datastream directly instead of using the file-upload "feature"?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the library you use on the front end, it should be possible to base64 encode the file and then send it as regular post data to PHP, thus avoiding writing the file to disk. There would be added overhead, of course, and you will end up sending more data over the wire this way. But, it can work (I've done it, though scrapped the idea due to the additional bandwidth usage).

Your backend will need to properly decode the data and handle it from there. I would recommend chunking the data if you do it this way so you can retry failed portions without having to upload the entire file again.

Comment: To make sure I understand what you're proposing: you're saying use javascript to base64 encode the file, and take the result and submit it to the backend as if it were the contents of a regular textarea (as if the user had base64 encoded the file and pasted it into a form field.)  Do I have that right?